# How to say "Hybrid" in Japanese. Or is there a word for it?

Tags: translation, words

Is there a word for "hybrid" in Japanese? Hybrid as in for animals or any and all Japanese words for cross species animals or two animals joined together. Preferable if all words for such is given because i need the shortest possible word(one or two syllable word) for hybrid animals or cross species animals. But if all possible words are given it would help the most.

Comment: Searching for "Hybrid" in [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8) main page leads to [ハイブリッド](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%89)... which in turn contains many occurrences of [雑種](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%91%E7%A8%AE)

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is 交雑種{こうざつしゅ} or 異種交配種{いしゅこうはいしゅ}.　https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%A4%E9%9B%91

Comment: Don’t those words refer to the action of crossbreeding itself as opposed to the resulting type of animal? I think 雑種 (or maybe 交雑**種**) is more on the mark...

Comment: @Darius Jahandarie Thank you for teaching.

Comment: The word i was looking for was 交差 Kousa. It's a two syllable word that i think represents genetic crossing?? as said by this website https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=25919&word_definition_id=2442

i'd love to get the validity of that.